# Algorithm - Max number of grains that can be transported

Tags: algorithm

I came across an interview question asked at Google which I can not solve:

> There is a pile of `N` kg grains at an oasis located in a distance of `D` km to a town. The grains need to be transported by a camel cart whose initial location is at the oasis. The cart can carry `C` kg of grains at a time. The camel uses the grains as fuel while transporting them. It consumes `F` kg/km.
>
> Write a function that computes the maximum amount of grains (`X` kg) that can be transported to the town.

---

I tried to use recursion but I couldn't get much further without confusing myself.

Here's what I have so far:

```
number of transports = N / C

fuel amount for distance D = D * F

X = N - ((number of transports) * 2 * (fuel amount for distance D))
```

Comment: Hint: the camel always starts each round-trip with `C` kilograms of grain. Hint 2: If the camel unloads all the grain at it destination, it will starve on the way back. Hint 3: the camel does not need to return to the oasis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that N, D, C and F are inputs, -

```
float computeMaxGrains(float N, float D, float C, float F)
{
    //Case when the cart can carry all grains at once
    if(N <= C)
    {
        float remainingGrains = N - D*F;
        if(remainingGrains >= 0)
        {
            return remainingGrains;
        }
        else
        {
            //out of fuel
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Grains consumed per Km = (Total Number of Trips) * F
    // Total Number of Trips = 2*(N/C) + 1
    float grainsConsumedPerKm = (float) (2*(Math.floor(N/C)) + 1);

    // Remaining grains after Camels fuel = C*(N/C - 1)
    float remainingGrains = (float) (C*(Math.floor(N/C)));

    // Distance that the Camel is able to travel before the camel is 
    // 1 less round trip = 
    // (N - Remaining Grains) / grainsConsumedPerKm
    // From equation N - (grainsConsumedPerKm * distanceTravelled) = 
    // Remaining Grains
    float distanceTravelled = (N - remainingGrains) / grainsConsumedPerKm;

    if(distanceTravelled >= D)
    {
        return N - (D * grainsConsumedPerKm);
    }

    //Use recursion for every 1 less round trip
    return computeMaxGrains(remainingGrains, D-distanceTravelled, C, F);
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the great explanation takyon and for showing how recursion could help here.

Comment: I think you missed multiplying by F while calculating grainsConsumedPerKm?

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is best worked iteratively, forwards. I'm going to split out the decision points. If I were writing one formula, I would use ?: All results are in Kg.

```
The first question is whether there is enough grain, and cart capacity, to 
justify an initial trip from oasis to town. The camel would eat FD, so 
if FD >= min(N,C) the answer is 0

If FD < min(N,C), the net amount transferred on the initial oasis to town 
trip is min(N,C)-FD. 

The camel is now in town, the remaining grain pile is N-min(N,C), and we 
have to decide whether to send it back again. If C <= 2FD, no round trip
can be profitable.

Otherwise consider a round trip with at least C remaining at the oasis. That 
gains net C-2FD (FD put in the cart in town to keep the camel fed getting 
to the oasis, C-FD remaining in the cart when it gets back to town).

If N>C, we can do floor((N-C)/C) of those round trips, net gain 
floor((N-C)/C)*(C-2FD).

After doing the initial run and any full cart round trips, the remaining 
grain pile is N%C, the remainder on dividing N by C.

If N%C > 2FD it is worth doing a final trip to empty the grain pile, with 
an additional net gain of N%C-2FD.
```

Comment: Really clear analysis, but it would help to explicitly mention the possibility that C-2FD could be negative (i.e. it's possible that it's a net loss to take a round trip from the town to the oasis and back, even if the very first trip is a net gain).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks - I had that sentence in a draft, and somehow dropped it. I've edited my answer to put it back in.

Comment: Thanks Patricia for the detailed analysis.

Answer (score 0):

As a idea, while there is more than D*F grain in the oasis the camel will travel, with C kg, or however much is left in the oasis. The camel consumes D*F kg on the trip there, drops off his load - 2*D*F kg of grain and returns if there is enough grain left to warrant the return journey.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess. I am not absolutely sure.

Let G(x) denote the maximum amount of grain transported to a distance x from the source. 
Then

```
G(x+1)= (G(x)/C)*(C-2F) + max(F,G(x)%C - F)
```

Now, G(0)=N and we need to find G(D) using the above formulation.

The second term max(F,G(x)%C-F) denotes

1. F = when he does not come back to collect the remaining grains in
   last visit
2. G(x)%C - F =remaining grain in the last visit and then consumes F to go back to the destination